# What is the proper way to initialize a UIViewController using Swift when not using Storyboards?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I want to get rid of the Storyboards in my project. Everything is written in code but I still have UIViewController(s) as reference.

When trying to present a UIViewController I normally use the method shown below and I'm able to access variables for that particular UIViewController.

```
func presentAttributeOptions(_ attribute: Attribute, controller: ProductViewController) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboards.Product, bundle: nil)
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Controllers.Attributes) as! AttributeOptionsViewController

    destination.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    destination.definesPresentationContext = true
    destination.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    destination.attribute = attribute
    destination.selectOptionDelegate = controller
    present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, removing the reference to the Storyboard and using the method shown below, I get errors such as for this example "Value of type 'ProductViewController' has no member 'attribute'" and "Value of type 'ProductViewController' has no member 'selectOptionDelegate'"

```
func presentAttributeOptions(_ attribute: Attribute, controller: ProductViewController) {

    let destination = ProductViewController()

    destination.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    destination.definesPresentationContext = true
    destination.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    destination.attribute = attribute
    destination.selectOptionDelegate = controller
    present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I found several answers but none seemed to work like for example adding the following init() methods shown below to the UIViewController. What am I missing?

```
// This allows you to initialize your custom UIViewController without a nib or bundle.
convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

// This extends the superclass.
override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

// This is also necessary when extending the superclass.
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") // or see Roman Sausarnes's answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just see this :

- with storyboard, destination is of type AttributeOptionsViewController
- without, destination is of type ProductionViewController

That may be a cause